# <div> element not getting centered using justify-content:center;

Tags: html, css

Using `justify-content:center;` does not generate the required results as shown in the pictures.

```css
.box {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin:10px ;
}

.flex{
    margin:10px;
    border:3px solid black;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex"><p>
    Lets learn about Flexbox.Flexbox needs a parent 
    container in order to work elements inside of that container
    these elements can be centered and adjusted easily.
</p>
<div class="box" id="box1">Box1</div>
<div class="box" id="box2">Box2</div>
<div class="box" id="box3">Box3</div>
<div class="box" id="box4">Box4</div>
<div class="box" id="box5">Box5</div>
<div class="box" id="box6">Box6</div>
</div>
```

Desired:

[image: Desired]

Actual:

[image: Actual]

Comment: did you try align-content, align items, align self, justify items?

Comment: Yes I tried that. Sadly,same results in each case.

Comment: use `flex-shrink` and `flex-grow` if you don't want to leave empty space in your layout.

Comment: You have been given many answers to your question. Please select one of the many answers you like best and mark this question as resolved by checking the box to the left of the answer. Thank.

Comment: @PeterDarmis yes I will try that.Thankyou for the help.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov Yes sir..I did not know that..will do it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your sections with div, and set `flex-direction: column` to the parent container. This way your `flex-wrap` will work correctly. Now, as in your picture the desired result.

```css
.box {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin:10px ;
}

.boxes {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    width: calc(600px + 60px);
    max-width: 100%;
}

.flex{
    margin:10px;
    border:3px solid black;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <p>
      Lets learn about Flexbox.Flexbox needs a parent 
      container in order to work elements inside of that container
      these elements can be centered and adjusted easily.
  </p>
  <div class="boxes">
  <div class="box" id="box1">Box1</div>
  <div class="box" id="box2">Box2</div>
  <div class="box" id="box3">Box3</div>
  <div class="box" id="box4">Box4</div>
  <div class="box" id="box5">Box5</div>
  <div class="box" id="box6">Box6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wanted to solve it without using any other tags but your method is easy and compavt.Thankyou.

Comment: You are using a `flex wrap: wrap`, which means that everything on the elements, including the `upper text`, will be affected by the `flex wrap`. Therefore, it makes sense to give the boxes a `parent div`. I was glad to help you :-)

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this. I hope , It will resolve your issue.**
Use flex-basis: 100% for p tag.

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: calc((100% / 3) - 10px);
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}
p {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.flex {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="flex"><p>
    Lets learn about Flexbox.Flexbox needs a parent 
    container in order to work elements inside of that container
    these elements can be centered and adjusted easily.
    </p>
<div class="box" id="box1">Box1</div>
<div class="box" id="box2">Box2</div>
<div class="box" id="box3">Box3</div>
<div class="box" id="box4">Box4</div>
<div class="box" id="box5">Box5</div>
<div class="box" id="box6">Box6</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box {
    height: 200px;
    width:  calc((100% / 3) - 10px);
    background-color: blue;
    margin:10px ;
}

.flex{
    margin:10px;
    border:3px solid black;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex"><p>
    Lets learn about Flexbox.Flexbox needs a parent 
    container in order to work elements inside of that container
    these elements can be centered and adjusted easily.
</p>
<div class="box" id="box1">Box1</div>
<div class="box" id="box2">Box2</div>
<div class="box" id="box3">Box3</div>
<div class="box" id="box4">Box4</div>
<div class="box" id="box5">Box5</div>
<div class="box" id="box6">Box6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also set `width` to `p` and solve this. In the snippet below `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` are used, you can check the ouput also in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zm7wpkgx/)

```css
.box {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 10px;
  flex-grow: 4;
  flex-shrink: 4;
}

.flex {
  margin: 10px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex p {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <p>
    Lets learn about Flexbox.Flexbox needs a parent container in order to work elements inside of that container these elements can be centered and adjusted easily.
  </p>
  <div class="box" id="box1">Box1</div>
  <div class="box" id="box2">Box2</div>
  <div class="box" id="box3">Box3</div>
  <div class="box" id="box4">Box4</div>
  <div class="box" id="box5">Box5</div>
  <div class="box" id="box6">Box6</div>
</div>
```